# how do I use @media queries properly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My current website layout: [Screenshot 1](http://image.prntscr.com/image/5c2449543360440ba6f5ece458c6b2ce.png)

I used a div with a wrap id to center the site:

```
#wrap {
width: 70%;
margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

but now it obviously also makes it 70% width on mobile which looks bad: [SC2](http://image.prntscr.com/image/d5d63bc5f40f4511b4fc91d3886e6992.png)

I did try using media queries, the one with max-device-width specified by itself and also the ones that are on the bootstrap website under the CSS section, everytime I used any of those I removed the original #wrap css code, but nothing at all worked, my website would just go to being 100% on all devices and even if I made it 70% on mobile (just as a test) it was still the same everywhere, like there was no css code for the wrap id at all.

Sorry if it's a dumb question, i'm just lost and really want to make my site 100% at a certain (tablet-mobile) breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
@media (min-width: 768px)  {
    .mymenu {
      width: 20%;
    }
}
```